# Loading Bootstrap from component.html file

Tags: html, css

This code works, bootstrap is loaded inside of the head tag.

```html
<html>    
    <head>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--some stuff-->
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I put that code in a component.html file and import it:

```html
<html>    
    <head>
        <link rel="import" href="component.html" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--some stuff-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Bootstrap doesn't work.
Can someone help me?

component.html:

```html
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: The error message is very clear: it seems you haven't loaded jQuery (or at all) before loading Bootstrap.

Comment: Can you post the component.html code?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to place this script tag, just before the closing body tag

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery library must be loaded First** or prior to this https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js file.

As this bootstrap.js is written using Jquery itself we need the main library to be loaded first so that the code inside the bootstrap file is meaningful, Else the browser compiler has no clue of the code, Hence the error.

Comment: @UrosBojanic that means the details you have given in the question posted and the scenario in your code is different. Can you provide your html page code, so that we can be more clear on the issue